# visible-xs React boostrap?

Tags: reactjs

I want to change my website to React. So I am changing the normal bootstrap to React bootstrap. I have just a simple question, what's the equivalent of Bootstrap **visible-xs** in React bootstrap? Like in simple bootstrap we have 'hidden-xs' and we use xsHidden in Reactboostrap.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into that today!  visible-xs went away in bootstrap 4, and react-bootstrap 1.0 now uses bootstrap 4.  The same is true of hidden-xs (and in all of the various sizes... hidden-sm, hidden-md, etc.)

In my case `<Row className="visible-xs">` becomes `<Row bsPrefix="d-block d-sm-none">`

The [bootstrap documentation has a nice table](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/) on how to convert to the new styles